# DB inserts in a Django app gradually get slower as more inserts are executed

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, performance, django-rest-framework

I am inserting a large amount of rows to a Postgresql db using Django ORM bulk_create(). I have roughly the following code:

```
entries = []
start = time()
for i, row in enumerate(initial_data_list):
    serializer = serializer_class(data=row, **kwargs)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    entries.append(MyModel(**serializer.initial_data))
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        MyModel.objects.bulk_create(entries)
        end = time()
        _logger.info('processed %d inserts... (%d seconds per batch)' % (i, end-start))
        start = time()
        entries = []
```

Measured execution times:

```
processed 1000 inserts... (16 seconds per batch)
processed 2000 inserts... (16 seconds per batch)
processed 3000 inserts... (17 seconds per batch)
processed 4000 inserts... (18 seconds per batch)
processed 5000 inserts... (18 seconds per batch)
processed 6000 inserts... (18 seconds per batch)
processed 7000 inserts... (19 seconds per batch)
processed 8000 inserts... (19 seconds per batch)
processed 9000 inserts... (20 seconds per batch)
```

etc., the time keeps growing as more insertions are made. The requests run inside a transaction using the Django settings DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = True, however, turning it off does not seem to have any effect. DEBUG mode is turned off.

Some observations:

- When the request is finished, and I execute an identical request, the measured times look pretty much identical: Start from decently low, and begin growing from there. No process-restart between the requests.
- The effect is the same, whether I'm doing individual insertions using serializer.save(), or bulk_create().
- The execution time of the bulk_create() line itself keeps about the same, a bit more than half a seconds.
- If I remove the insertion entirely, the loop is executed at constant time, which points to something going on in the db-connection layer, that slows down the entire process as the quantity of insertions grows...
- During execution, The Python process' memory consumption pretty much stays constant after reaching the first bulk_create(), as does Postgres process memory, so that does not look to be the problem.

What is happening that makes the inserts grow slower? Since new requests start fast again (without process-restart needed), could I perform some sort of clean-ups during the request to restore speed?

Comment: Are you running with `DEBUG=True`? If so you might want to use [`reset_queries()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running). Is this code running in a transaction?

Comment: Thanks, updated the question. DEBUG is False, and the requests are executed inside a transaction, as per Django's DB settings ATOMIC_REQUESTS=True. Also tried reset_queries() already, to no effect.

Comment: If `DEBUG = False`, then `reset_queries()` will have no effect. You could try decorating the view with `@transaction.non_atomic_requests` to see whether the long running transaction is having an effect.

Comment: Tried disabling ATOMIC_REQUESTS entirely from settings.py. While there was more variance in the measured times, ultimately the execution time still kept growing by about the same rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found working was to disable ATOMIC_REQUESTS in settings.py, which allows me to call db.connection.close() and db.connection.connect() every now and then during the request, to keep the execution time from growing.

Answer (score 0):

Does `MyModel` have any indexes at the database level? Could it be that those are affecting the processing time by being updated after each insertion?

You could try to remove the indexes (if there are any) and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Since new request take off fast again, I doubt it can be because of that. For curiosity I tried anyway, to no effect. I wouldn't have been able to give up those indexes entirely anyway, though.

Answer (score 0):

Big disclaimer : i'm still a novice so...

From what i can see in your code is 
for 1000 entries   16seconds
for 9000 entries   20seconds
for me it looks like a normal thing that time increase, inserting more entries takes more time no??
Sorry if i'm misunderstanding something

Comment: The point is that the time to insert 1000 entries is not constant, but increasing gradually. In the last measurement, the time to insert was 20 seconds, while in the first round it was only 16 seconds. Notice that the entries list is emptied after each insert.